# Cannot start sql server under domain user

Tags: sql-server, kerberos

I am doing a double hop kerberos authentication from my iis to my sql server and for that I need the SQLEXPRESS service to run under a domain user.

Domain name: domain.test
service user: sqlSrv
sql server computer name : SQL

When I try to start the service this is the error I get:

```
Windows Could not start the SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) on Local Computer. 
For more information, review the System Event Log. 
If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 17058.
```

The error I see in the Event Log is:

```
initerrlog: Could not open error log file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQ.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG'.
Operating System error = 5 (Access is denied).
Source: MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
Event ID: 17058
```

I've set up the following SPNs:

```
setspn -L domain.test\sqlSrv
setspn -A SQLEXPRESS/SQL:1433 domain.test\sqlSrv
setspn -A SQLEXPRESS/SQL.domain.test:1433 domain.test\sqlSrv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
initerrlog: Could not open error log file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQ.1\MSSQL\LOG\ERRORLOG'.
Operating System error = 5 (Access is denied).
```

Obviously you just replaced the service account on an existing installation. This is **not** supported. You need to install the service from scratch, using the desired service account.

While theoretically you could go through [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143504.aspx) and figure out what permissions are needed (in fact, figure out what local groups the service account needs to be member of), that would assume that you know what the heck you're doing.

Do it by the book. Install the service to use the desired service account. Read and follow [Install SQL Server 2014 from the Command Prompt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.120%29.aspx). The service account install command line parameters are described [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28v=sql.120%29.aspx#Accounts):

> SQL Server Database Engine:
>
> - Service account: `/SQLSVCACCOUNT`
> - Accountpassword: `/SQLSVCPASSWORD`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I wanted to start sqlserver service.The event viewer showed this message as you mentioned.I did my best to set permission unfortunately it did not work for me.The problem was related to "ERROLOG",its size was about 1G and it there was not the file name such as "**ERRORLOG.1,ERROLLOG.2**,..", so I deleted after making backup of it.at the problem disappeared.
I hope it is functional for you.